# Importing CSV data into a table in mySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, import-csv

Ok so I am trying to import data from a CSV file into mySQL database table. The table is called serial_code, however when I try to upload the CSV file I have an error message. I have tried taking the column names out, also adding NULL to the last column EngineSerialCode and I have also viewed the CSV in a text editor and it shows the columns correctly with , comma.

> Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1.

**Version of phpMyAdmin and mySQL**

[image: mySQL version]

**Database Fields**

[image]

**CSV Fields I want to import**

[image: CSV]

Comment: How you are mapping them through, you have 4th column exists in the database table (engine serialcode)

Comment: @BHouse Even when I add that column it displays that error. I am added them through "import" > browse file >

Columns separated with: , Comma
Columns enclosed with: "
Columns escaped with: \
Lines terminated with: auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the issue and it was quite frustrating. I had a serial code in my data that had a "," comma instead of a "-". Also I noticed that my CSV file EngineSerialCode was placed in column E and not D as I only have 4 columns in my database. From the image column C is overlapping column D hence my mistake.

[image: comma and wrong column error]